# SQL query to fetch latest 3 sends based on date and then group the records

Tags: sql

I have a table with email `sent_date` and `click_date` for each product id(`pid`) that looks like below example:

| email | pid | sent_date | click_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A@gmail.com | 1001 | 1 May 2021 21:12 | null |
| A@gmail.com | 1001 | 2 May 2021 21:12 | null |
| A@gmail.com | 1001 | 3 May 2021 21:12 | 3 May 2021 21:12 |
| B@gmail.com | 1001 | 1 May 2021 21:12 | 1 May 2021 21:12 |
| B@gmail.com | 1001 | 2 May 2021 21:12 | 2 May 2021 21:12 |
| B@gmail.com | 1001 | 3 May 2021 21:12 | 3 May 2021 21:12 |
| A@gmail.com | 1007 | 1 May 2021 21:12 | 1 May 2021 21:12 |
| A@gmail.com | 1007 | 2 May 2021 21:12 | null |
| A@gmail.com | 1007 | 3 May 2021 21:12 | 3 May 2021 21:12 |
| A@gmail.com | 1007 | 4 May 2021 21:12 | null |
| A@gmail.com | 1007 | 5 May 2021 21:12 | null |
| A@gmail.com | 1007 | 6 May 2021 21:12 | null |

Out of this table, I need to build a new table called "Last 3 sends_clickCount".

So the final table should look like below:

| email | pid. | clickCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A@gmail.com | 1001 | 1 |
| B@gmail.com | 1001 | 3 |
| A@gmail.com | 1007 | null |

I want to consider the click for only latest 3 sends and according to `pid`.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @sfmc_newbie please share the create table and insert scripts also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.email,
       t1.pid,
       count(case when rn <= 3 then t1.click_date else null end) clickcount
  from (
select t1.email,
       t1.pid,
       row_number() over(partition by t1.email, t1.pid order by t1.sent_date desc) rn,
       t1.click_date
  from tab1 t1 
) t1
 group by t1.email,
       t1.pid
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp 
(  email varchar(20)
  ,pid    int
  ,sent_date datetime
  ,click_date datetime
) 

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES 
('A@gmail.com',1001,'1 May 2021 21:12',null)
,('A@gmail.com',1001,'2 May 2021 21:12',null)
,('A@gmail.com',1001,'3 May 2021 21:12','3 May 2021 21:12')
,('B@gmail.com',1001,'1 May 2021 21:12','1 May 2021 21:12')
,('B@gmail.com',1001,'2 May 2021 21:12','2 May 2021 21:12')
,('B@gmail.com',1001,'3 May 2021 21:12','3 May 2021 21:12')
,('A@gmail.com',1007,'1 May 2021 21:12','1 May 2021 21:12')
,('A@gmail.com',1007,'2 May 2021 21:12',null)
,('A@gmail.com',1007,'3 May 2021 21:12','3 May 2021 21:12')
,('A@gmail.com',1007,'4 May 2021 21:12',null)
,('A@gmail.com',1007,'5 May 2021 21:12',null)
,('A@gmail.com',1007,'6 May 2021 21:12',null)


SELECT email,
       pid,
       clickCount
FROM
(
       SELECT *
              ,RANK() over (partition by email,pid order by sent_date desc) as ranking
       FROM #temp
) as ranktable
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN ranktable.click_date IS NOT NULL 
                         THEN COUNT(*) 
                    ELSE 
                              NULL
                    END AS clickCount 
              FROM #temp AS t 
              WHERE t.pid = ranktable.pid 
              AND t.email = ranktable.email 
              AND click_date IS NOT NULL
            ) as counttable
WHERE ranking = 1

drop table #temp
```

The coding mentioned above should be used on `MSSQL` (SQL Server 2005 above)

First, use `rank` to find out which are latest 3 sent_date.

Second, use `outer apply` to find the click count. If the latest click_date is `null`, then return `null` else return clickCount

Comment: `outer apply` is non-standard SQL (as is `#temp`) - please mention the DBMS for which this is valid

Answer (score 0):

A query like below may do the trick

```
with cte as (
SELECT *
,RANK() over (partition by email,pid order by sent_date desc) as ranking
FROM #temp
)
select email,pid
,sum(case when click_date is null then null else 1 end) clickcount
from cte
where ranking <=3
group by email,pid
```